# Scheduled Batch Errors

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have 2 batch apex classes, each with a scheduler class. I am trying to run them sequentially but I am getting 2 errors on the 2nd batch class in my logs:

**Error #1**:

```
FATAL_ERROR|System.StringException: Only CronTrigger IDs and batch, future, and queueable job IDs are supported.

Class.AccountTotalReferralsBatch.finish: line 23, column 1
```

**Error #2:**

```
FATAL_ERROR|System.StringException: Job does not exist or is already aborted.

Class.AccountTotalReferralsBatch.finish: line 23, column 1
```

The batches do update as expected, but then it seems the errors occur after the updates. Is there something else I am missing from my classes?

**Batch #1:**

```
public class AccountTotalEncountersBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) amt 
            FROM Encounters__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :scope AND Age__c<366 GROUP BY Account__c]);
            
        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult amount = results.get(record.Id);
            if(amount != null) {
                record.Encounters__c = (Decimal)amount.get('amt');
            } else {
                record.Encounters__c = null;
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            b.Scheduled_Id__c = system.scheduleBatch(new AccountTotalReferralsBatch(),'Batch 2',2);
        upsert b;
    }
}
```

**Batch #2:**

```
public class AccountTotalReferralsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) amt 
            FROM Referral__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :scope AND Age__c<366 GROUP BY Account__c]);
            
        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult amount = results.get(record.Id);
            if(amount != null) {
                record.Referrals__c = (Decimal)amount.get('amt');
            } else {
                record.Referrals__c = null;
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            System.abortJob(b.Scheduled_Id__c);
    }         
}
```

Comment: when the second finish() executes, the job scheduled by batch 1 will naturally end and it does not need to be aborted

Comment: @cropredy So I don't need the System.abortJob statement in my 2nd batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good reason for your first batch job to schedule the second batch job 2 minutes later. A simpler approach is to use `Database.executeBatch(..)` which will put it on the queue and it will execute when resources are available.

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Database.executeBatch(new AccountTotalReferralsBatch());
}
```

Then, the finish of the second batch can look like this:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
}
```

If you need to pass arguments from the first batch to the second batch, pass them in the constructor:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Database.executeBatch(new AccountTotalReferralsBatch(arg1,arg2, ...));
}
```

Comment: Great thanks!  That worked.